# How to change default version of PHP from 4 to 5?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My server have default php version of 4, so when I run some script saved as .php I have PHP 4.
I want to change it, so I don't must use .php5 extension, I heared that there are something in .htacess.
I want to run eyeOS on my server, but I don't want to change every line from .php to .php5
Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AddHandler php5-script .php into .htaccess

Comment: just type "AddHandler php5-script .php" into .htaccess?

Comment: yep, that's should be all, it works for me. If it doesn't, try restarting server, if even that doesn't work you have to put that in apache config file.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be 'AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php '?